# Probability of choosing $n$ different numbers out of $\{1,\dots,10\}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider the set $\{1,\dots,10\}$, and suppose we draw $4$ numbers with substitution. I want to calculate the probability of drawing $n$ different numbers, with $n=0,2,3,4$. I omit the value $n=1$ because drawing $1$ different number does not make much sense.

Let $\Omega=\{1,\dots,10\}^4$ be the sample space, then $|\Omega|=10^4$. Also, $A_n$ be the event "$n$ different numbers are drawn", for $n=0,2,3,4$. My reasoning is as follows:

$A_0$ and $A_4$ are easy:

$$P(A_0)=\frac{10}{10^4}$$

$$P(A_4)=\frac{{10 \choose 4}4!}{10^4}$$

Now, $A_2$ can be split into two cases: choosing two pairs of numbers, say $aabb$, or choosing one number $3$ times, say $aaab$. Given the definition of $\Omega$, order matters, hence:

$$P(A_2)=\frac{{10 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}2! +{10 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}2!}{10^4}$$

where ${4\choose k}$ comes from selecting $k$ places to put the smallest chosen number in.

Is this correct?

Further, to calculate $P(A_3)$, I can add up what I've got so far and substract that number from $1$, but this would obviously rely on $P(A_2)$ being correct. Alternatively, I've tried to calculate $P(A_3)$ directly, but can't seem to get the probabilities to add up o $1$, so there's a mistake somewhere. For reference, I was thinking of:

$$P(A_3)=\frac{{10 \choose 3}{4 \choose 2}3!}{10^4}$$

since we choose a triplet of numbers, $2$ places to put the smallest number in, fill out the remaining places from left to right with the other two numbers in increasing order, and then move the numbers around.

So, where's the mistake(s)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is in P(A2), see ans below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget about the denominator $10^4$, which is constant,
and use the multinomial coefficient for a uniform approach:

$0$ *different:*
$\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{4} = 10$

$2$ *different:* pattern $2-2\; or\; 3-1$
$\binom{10}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2,2} + \binom{10}{1,1}\cdot\binom{4}{3,1}= 630$

$3$ *different:* pattern $2-1-1$
$\binom{10}{2,1}\cdot\binom{4}{2,1,1} = 4320$

$4$ *different:*
$\binom{10}{4}\cdot\binom{4}{1,1,1,1} = 5040$